# Difference between Microsoft Publisher, online editors like Ribbet and Photoshop while preparing business cards

Tags: adobe-photoshop

While designing business cards, I wonder why one should use applications like Photoshop when it is easier to use online editors like [Ribbet](http://www.ribbet.com/) or Microsoft Publisher. I prepared business card using Microsoft Publisher

[image]

(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-ojy1_hme1is/V3K4GDND9SI/AAAAAAAABPQ/BFaobRVIwoEis8TJOa-nJCnC328rjFCBgCK4B/s1600/RBVisitingCard.jpg) and Ribbet (https://image.jimcdn.com/app/cms/image/transf/dimension=260x10000:format=jpg/path/s0ca43f569d2c6db0/image/ic4cd46f6fc08196e/version/1469454670/image.jpg). Is there way to improve image quality through using other applications like Photoshop? In other words, what the limitations are of using Microsoft Publisher, Ribbet if any over Photoshop while preparing business cards.

Answer (score 3):

#### You should not

There is a main concepts regarding images. Either they are bitmap or vector. In a photo or background there is no problem, you use what you need, but the texts get "screened", which causes them to be blurry.

[image]

That online aplication you mention produces, not only a bitmap, but a low quality one for print.

#### Publisher

Publisher does produce a vector output, but it lacks of a lot of features needed for a professional output. Its main goal is to make documents that will be printed in an office environment, perhaphs a report which will be printed 50 copies on a laser or inkjet printer.

If your project will be printed like that, in a laser printer you could use it.

If you do not care about quality you can use whatever is at hand.

---

I really need to say this. No offense intended, but a serious concern about your business and image.

You should look for a designer.

Your business cards are not business cards. They are a small "flyer" where you want to compact a lot of unneccesary information not very happily distributed.

[image]

[image]

Compare them to any image on a simple google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=business+card

The "quality" of the output issue pales compared to the low quality "design".

**A good design is an investment.** It is sometimes a lot more important than physical instalations, more important than a business suit.

Comment: I completely agree with Rafael. If you want your face to the public to look good, and professional, you need to find a competent designer.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use Photoshop to create business cards. **Photoshop is great photo editing software, but it's not page layout software.**

For page layout, use page layout software. The industry standard is InDesign. You'll want to create a document that's the proper size, which is usually 3.5x2". Give it a .125" bleed. Export as PDF and make sure it's 300dpi and CMYK. That's the correct setting for printing documents professionally.

(It might sound weird to think of a tiny business card as a "page" or "document", but that's what it is.)

With that said, you could certainly use Photoshop to create imagery which will go on your business card. You could also use Illustrator to draw vector logos or icons. Place everything into InDesign, layout your text and images, and you're all set.